# Caching data to spare mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I have a PHP application that is executed up to one hundred times simultaneously, and very often. (its a telegram anti-spam bot with 250k+ users)
The script itself makes various DB calls (tickers update, counters etc.) but it also load each time some more or less 'static' data from the database, like regexes or json config files.
My script is also doing image manipulation, so the server's CPU and RAM are sometimes under pressure.

Some days ago i ran into a problem, the apache2 OOM-Killer was killing the mysql server process due to lack of avaible memory. The mysql server were not restarting automaticaly, leaving my script broken for hours.

I already made some code optimisations that enabled my server to breathe, but what i'm looking now, is to have some caching method to store data between script executions, with the possibility to update them based on a time interval.
First i thought about flat file where i could serialize data, but i would like to know if it is a good idea or not regarding performances.

In my case, is there a benefit of using caching data over mysql queries ?
What are the pro/con, regarding speed of access, speed of execution ?
Finaly, what caching method should i implement ?
I know that the simplest solution is to upgrade my server capacity, I plan to do so anytime soon.

Server is running Debian 11, PHP 8.0
Thank you.

Comment: It really depends on how complex your queries are, how much (if any) processing of the fetched data you do before dishing it out -- and how conservative your "on the fly" code is in conserving memory (e.g. you don't have several "versions" of large datasets floating around concurrently). If the answer to any of these is a "significant yes", then a cache layer may come in handy. If you're just serving out straight data, your queries are simple enough, and you have indexes in place, then you may need to look elsewhere for optimization opportunities.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS; 
AND OS information, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you could use a NoSQL to provide those queries it would speed up dramatically.

Now if this is a no go, you can go old school and keep that "static" data in the filesystem.

You can then create a timer of your own that runs, for example, every 20 minutes to update the files.

When you ask info regarding speed of access, speed of execution the answer will always be "depends" but from what you said it would be better to access the file system that being constantly querying the database for the same info...

Answer (score 1):

The complexity, consistency, etc, lead me to recommend against a caching layer.  Instead, let's work a bit more on other optimizations.

OOM implies that something is tuned improperly.  Show us what you have in my.cnf.  How much RAM do you have?  How much RAM des the image processing take?  (PHP's image* library is something of a memory hog.)  We need to start by knowing how much RAM can MySQL can have.

For tuning, please provide `GLOBAL STATUS` and `VARIABLES`.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

That link also shows how to gather the slowlog.  In it we should be able to find the "worst" queries and work on optimizing them.  For "one hundred times simultaneously", even fast queries need to be further optimized.  When providing the 'worst' queries, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Another technique is to *decrease* the number of children that Apache is allowed to run.  Apache will queue up others.  "Hundreds" is too many for Apache or MySQL; it is better to wait to start some of them rather than having "hundreds" stumbling over each other.